Next.js revalidateTag not working as expected with route handler
I'm working on a Next JS application where I need to revalidate tags after a user submits a quest. The revalidateTag seems to not trigger the route handler correctly. Here's the setup:
Also, for all my road work, when I actualize the page the function getQuestStatuses is called and work t is just the revalidateTag who don't do this job.
I use other revalidateTag on my website who work perfectly.
But for that one i don't find the issue.
I am on nextjs 14 on app router mode and also the road who is call is on express side but the issue is not on express side.
**Function to fetch quest statuses and update cookies:
**
export async function getQuestStatuses() {
  const wallet = await getCookie('wallet');
  const url = `${backendUrl}/api/next/quest/status/${wallet}`;
  const tags = [`questStatus-${wallet}`];

  try {
    const res = await fetch(url, {
      next: { tags: tags },
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log('dataStatus', data);
    const newQuestStatuses = data.questCodatas;
    console.log('newQuestStatuses', newQuestStatuses);
    // Compare new data with previous data and update cookies if necessary
    if (
      newQuestStatuses.length !== previousQuestStatuses.length ||
      JSON.stringify(newQuestStatuses) !== JSON.stringify(previousQuestStatuses)
    ) {
      console.log('Updating quest status cookies');
      await updateQuestStatusCookies(newQuestStatuses);
      previousQuestStatuses = newQuestStatuses;
    }

    return newQuestStatuses;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Server error', error);
  }
}


**Function to revalidate tag after quest submission:
**
export async function postApproveQuest(formData: FormData) {
  const wallet = await getCookie('wallet');
  const discordConnect = await getCookie('discordConnect');

  const API_URL = `${backendUrl}/api/next/quest/approval`;

  formData.append('wallet', wallet);

  try {
    const res = await fetch(API_URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Cookie: `discordConnect=${discordConnect}`,
      },
      body: formData,
    });
    const data = await res.json();

    if (res.ok) {
      revalidateTag(`messagenotif-${wallet}`);
      revalidateTag(`questStatus-${wallet}`);
    }

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Server error', error);
  }
}


**Client component to call getQuestStatuses:
**
'use client';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { getQuestStatuses } from './Action';

interface Props {
  wallet: string;
}
export default function CookieForQuestPage({ wallet }: Props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    getQuestStatuses().then((data) => {
      console.log('Quest statuses updated:', data);
    });
  }, [wallet]);

  return null;
}


Despite this setup, the revalidateTag for questStatus-${wallet} doesn't seem to re-trigger the route handler to fetch the latest data and update the cookies. Other revalidateTag calls in my application work as expected.
What I've tried:
Verified that revalidateTag works for other tags.
Confirmed that the function updateQuestStatusCookies correctly updates/deletes cookies based on the quest statuses.
Logs and observations:
The console logs indicate that revalidateTag does not re-trigger the route handler for questStatus-${wallet}.
Any insights on what might be going wrong or additional debugging steps would be appreciated.
